Avalon's rock-paper-scissors
This puzzle is a symmetrical version of Three-player Avalon (transmitting private knowledge over a public channel). I came across this version (for which I think I have a solution) while looking for solution to the other problem (for which I do not).
Basic rules
Alice, Bob and Eve are playing a game. Alice and Bob are in the same team, the Talkers. Eve plays against them.
At the start of the round, Alice and Bob each draw a card from a deck containing rock, paper and scissors. Only Alice knows the card she picked; only Bob knows the card he picked. It is guaranteed that two different cards are selected, and all six combinations are equally probable.
During the round, Alice and Bob communicate under full view of Eve, for example by writing on a chalkboard. At time $t=0,2,4,\cdots$, Alice can write anything she wants, and both Bob and Eve will read it (and remember for the rest of the game). At time $t=1,3,5,\cdots$ Bob can write anything he wants, and both Alice and Eve will read it (and remember for the rest of the game).
If either Talker writes "I KNOW", they become the Speaker and the game enters the final phase. Communication stops and the Speaker must make the RPS-Guess: she or he writes whether they think their card beats the other Talker’s in a game of rock-paper-scissors. (As usual, rock beats scissors, scissors beat paper, and paper beats rock.) Then, Eve makes the Knowledge-Guess: she tries to guess a player’s card (more details later).
Talkers win if the Speaker correctly guesses if they win or lose the game of rock-paper-scissors, and Eve guesses incorrectly a card. If the Talker guessed incorrectly, or if Eve guessed accurately, Eve wins.
Variants
There are four variants of the game, combining two sets of possibilites :

The RPS-Guess

(1) is made in view of Eve, who can take that information into account when she makes the Knowledge-Guess
(2) is made secretely (for example in writing), and Eve does not know it when she makes the Knowledge-Guess


The Knowledge-Guess

(A) must be made about the card of the Speaker
(B) can be made, at Eve’s choice, about either player’s card



For instance, in variant 1B, Eve knows the Speaker’s announcement, and can choose to guess either the Speaker’s card or the card of his/her partner.
No secrets rule
Before the round starts, Alice and Bob may convene on a strategy for communication during the round; the strategy must be known to Eve. The strategy may involve drawing (pseudo-)random numbers, but these numbers cannot be shared (except via public channel communications, which Eve can read).
Eve has infinite computing power: for instance, given a non-deterministic function $f$ and an output $O$, she can immediately compute the set $\{(I,P(f(I)=O))\}$ (i.e. the probability that each possible input will generate the observed output). This prevents Alice and Bob from using a Diffie-Hellman key exchange.
Halt!
The Talkers’ strategy must almost surely lead to either player writing "I KNOW" within a finite number of steps. (Strategies must be submitted in advance to the organisers of the Avalon Rock-Paper-Scissors tournament, who have solved the halting problem through their psychic powers; a pair of Talkers submitting a non-halting strategy is disqualified.)
Coaching the Talkers
The Talkers come to you for advice.
Bob does not like taking decisions, and puzzles make his head hurt. He wants Alice to immediately write "I KNOW" as her first message, and guess randomly. This way, the whole stupid game is over without him making a single move or thinking about the different variants.
Alice reasons that, should she do as he suggests, Eve cannot do any better than guess randomly as well, under any of the variants. She calculates it gives the Talkers a probability $1/2\times 2/3 = 1/3$ to win (Alice guesses right with probability $1/2$ and Eve guesses wrong with probability $2/3$).
Alice does not like Bob’s hot-headed strategy, but she cannot come up with anything better in any of the variants.
Can you? What is the optimal strategy for either team, and what is the Talkers’ chance of winning?

By "almost surely", do you mean "halt with probability 1"?

@Lucenaposition yes (see Wikipedia).

I'm sure they can do better in every way but a simple improvement in variant 2A : Bob can just announce his card ("I have rock"). Now Alice can write "Win" or "Lose" with 100% certainty, and Eve can only guess Alice's card with probability 1/2. With this strategy, the Talkers win with probability 1/2.
